# Do Garrisoned units heal in AoE 4?

Tags: age-of-empires-iv

Do units garrisoned in defensive buildings (outposts and keeps) heal in AoE 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disappointingly (a sentiment expressed by others in [this](https://forums.ageofempires.com/t/no-garrison-healing-is-not-fun/179140) AoE IV forum), unlike AoE II garrisoned units do not regenerate health in AoE IV.

Aside from a ranged damage buff there is no healing that occurs when garrisoned. This may change in future updates if the player outcry is loud enough. For more details on the effects granted to garrisoned units please read the following link:
https://ageofempires.fandom.com//Garrison#Age_of_Empires_IV